Why is the three-term recurrence relation for Legendre polynomials called "Bonnet's formula"?
The three-term recurrence relation for Legendre polynomials $(n+1) P_{n+1}(x) - (2n+1) x P_n(x) + n P_{n-1}(x)=0$ is often referred to as "Bonnet's (recursion) formula". I assume he's the same "Bonnet" of Gauss-Bonnet theorem fame (Pierre Ossian Bonnet), but I couldn't find his original paper in which he derived the recurrence relation. Could anyone provide some reference on the history of the naming of this formula?

The original paper is
Thèse de mécanique. Sur le développement des fonctions en séries ordonnées suivant les fonctions $X_n$ et $Y_n$, Journal de Mathématiques Pures et Appliquées, Serie 1, Volume 17 (1852), pp. 265-300; see Theorem V at page 4 of the scan.
So, this time, the name of the formula is really due to its discoverer and is not a case of Stigler's law of eponymy.

It is not clear to me that the functions $X_{n}$ of theorem V in Bonnet's publication correspond to the Legendre polynomials $P_{n}$. It might improve the answer to point out where that connection is being made.

OK, I see it now. The remark following theorem 1 in the paper clearly indicates that the functions $X_{n}$ are the Legendre polynomials $P_{n}$.

@njuffa It is said in the first sentence of the work: "On sait que les fonctions $X_n$ et $Y_n$, introduites dans l'analyse par Legendre..."

See Recherches sur l'attraction des sphéroïdes homogènes

Thanks for the pointer. I find this remark in Bonnet's publication very straightforward linkage: "Remarque. On appelle $X_{n}$ le coefficient de $\alpha^{n}$ dans le développement de $\left(1-2 \alpha x + \alpha^{2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}.$"
